# ¿Cómo puedo añadir un submenú en mi navbar?

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

Estoy intentando crear un submenú para cuando mi navbar esté en formato móvil pero no consigo crear.

La versión de bootstrap es 4.1.3, JQuery es 3.4.1
Este es mi código HTML:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md justify-content-center topnav" style="background-color: rgb(2, 66, 118);" id="navbar-nav-three">
  <div class="dropdown navbar-toggler" style="background-color:white;border-radius:0 !important;">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
                </span>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <ul>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">DIPLOMA</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item mt-1 dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color:black !important;">
                    FAQ
                  </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="instrucciones.php">INSTRUCCIONES</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="audiencia.php">AUDIENCIA Y OBJETIVOS</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">TUTORIA</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">CERRAR SESIÓN</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-between align-items-center w-100" id="collapsingNavbar2">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-center">
      <li class="nav-item mt-1" id="block-list-li-one">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="a-navbar-home">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mt-1" id="block-list-li-two">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="a-navbar-gastro">DIPLOMA</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mt-1 dropdown" id="block-list-li-three">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    FAQ
                  </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="instrucciones.php">INSTRUCCIONES</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="audiencia.php">AUDIENCIA Y OBJETIVOS</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mt-1" id="block-list-li-three">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="a-navbar-colo">TUTORIA</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mt-1" id="block-list-li-three">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="a-navbar-colo">CERRAR SESIÓN</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

No consigo que haga la funcionalidad que abra un desplegable en el apartado **FAQ** cuando está en formato móvil, adjunto captura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado añadir otros navbar; en especial necesito que esté centrado, pero a la hora de verlo en formato móvil este no hace su funcionalidad. Mi idea es que se despliegue haciendo clic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No funciona porque `dropdown-submenu` fue removido en la [versión 3 de Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/6342). De todas maneras, con unas líneas de código con JQuery ya se logra obtener esta funcionalidad.

Eliminando el "menú duplicado", quedaría de esta manera:

```js
$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
    $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass("show");
  }
  var $subMenu = $(this).next(".dropdown-menu");
  $subMenu.toggleClass('show');


  $(this).parents('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown-submenu .show').removeClass("show");
  });

  return false;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md topnav" style="background-color: rgb(2, 66, 118);" id="navbar-nav-three">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="background-color:white;border-radius:0 !important;">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between align-items-center w-100" id="navbarNavDropdown" style="background-color:white;border-radius:0 !important;">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link mt-1">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link mt-1">DIPLOMA</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown mt-1">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                FAQ
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="instrucciones.php">INSTRUCCIONES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="audiencia.php">AUDIENCIA Y OBJETIVOS</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link mt-1">TUTORÍA</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-link mt-1">CERRAR SESIÓN</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Nótese que se omitieron varios id al reemplazar el código, el cual fue extraído de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024991).